# Universal Image Loader throws UnsupportedOperationException. Not sure why

Tags: android, exception, universal-image-loader

Everything is working great it would seem, however, UIL keeps throwing this exception. They are not fatal and are not crashing the app. My thoughts are that its just what UIL spits out when it can't find the image I'm sending it via a web uri.

Here is the exception below.

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: UIL doesn't support scheme(protocol) by default [/assets/attachments_missing/avatars/square_missing.png]. You should implement this support yourself (BaseImageDownloader.getStreamFromOtherSource(...))

com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.download.BaseImageDownloader.getStreamFromOtherSource(BaseImageDownloader.java:206)
com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.download.BaseImageDownloader.getStream(BaseImageDownloader.java:95)
com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.downloadImage(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:340)
com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.tryCacheImageOnDisc(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:307)
com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.tryLoadBitmap(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:249)
com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.run(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:131)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

Here is my configuration for UIL:

```
DisplayImageOptions defaultOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
    .cacheInMemory()
    .cacheOnDisc()
    .showStubImage(R.drawable.wm_new_thumb)
    .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.wm_new_thumb)
    .build();

    ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(this)
    .defaultDisplayImageOptions(defaultOptions)
    .build();

    ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
```

Answer (score 2):

if you want to load images from assets folder using [Android-Universal-Image-Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) then append `"assets://"` prefix with images paths in assets as:

```
String imageUri = "assets://attachments_missing/avatars/square_missing.png";
//... do same for other images..
```

and for more help see following issue regarding loading images from assets :

[Does Android-Universal-Image-Loader support Asset folder?](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/issues/123)