# Images not loading from assets folder using Universal Image Loader

Tags: android, universal-image-loader

I do exactly what [this guy suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16679639/universal-image-loader-throws-unsupportedoperationexception-not-sure-why) which is exactly the same as the creator of the Universal Image Loader, but I still get this error:

```
URI = assets://NMF0002_007.jpg
resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri: NMF0002_007.jpg
```

What should I look for to ensure that the images are recognised?

I use it like this:

```
//get the file name
String fileName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DatabaseHelper.FIELD_RESOURCE));
String imageUri = "assets://";
Log.d(TAG, "URI = " + imageUri + fileName);
ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(imageUri+fileName, holder.iv_details_resource);
```

This is my configuration:

```
//Get the imageloader.
ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();

//Create image options.
DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
    .cacheOnDisc() 
    .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.IN_SAMPLE_POWER_OF_2) 
    .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
    .build();

//Create a config with those options.
ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(getApplicationContext())
    .defaultDisplayImageOptions(options)
    .discCacheExtraOptions(480, 800, CompressFormat.JPEG, 75)
    .build();

//Initialise the imageloader.
imageLoader.init(config);
```

What am I doing wrong or missing?

Comment: Which files does `assets` folder in the project contain?

Comment: Images - no larger than 300KB .jpg files.

Comment: Turns out it was a .JPG and I was looking for a .jpg - LESSON: make sure you know what you're looking for and what you've got!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution - I was looking for .jpg and my file extension was .JPG

If NOSTRA can post some clever things to be on the lookout for I'll mark your answer as an official answer to my silliness.